Step up lFP battery cell voltage - from 44.8v to 53v
I have 50 Ah cells LFP 3.2 V. I connect 14 of them in series - giving me an output of 44.8 V (nominal).
I will use this battery pack to power an EV 2 wheel that requires 53 V to function. With a required discharge current of 40 A at output.
What is my best option to increase the voltage from 44.8 to 53 V?
Increasing the number of cells is not an option.
I tried a dc to dc boost converts available in the market. However they did give the enough output current. But did boost the voltage. Some of them are super bulky.
What is the best way to do this?

The motor almost certainly will operate over a range of voltages - it does not require exactly 53V. You may have to accept that the motor will not run as fast as if it is supplied 53v. Please provide a link to the details for the motor.

If you must have 53 V then a boost converter is the way to go.  You may have to design your own, since your requirements are somewhat unique.  You might want to do a 2-phase design (or more) to keep ripple current low.

The battery packs goes into an ebike, space is a concern. If I design a dc booster it will be hard to fit it in. Due to its bulky size.
However any circuits you can recommend here ?
Most common motor controllers in the current problem statement work over 53v. When I supply 44.8v its way to slow and performs poorly when load is applied to it. The controller requires 48v to 53v at 50amps.
Is there a dc to dc boost converter for battery packs that can support 44.8vdc to 53v at 50amps current rating ? Would be great if you can recommend something.

Big honking boost converter, two-phase.

So you have a 48-volt motor. The operational voltage range of a 48-volt battery system is 42 to 54 volts. Instead of supplying the motor with the correct battery voltage, you opted for something lower voltage. It will work as planned poorly.
When using LFp cells, 4S is required to equal a nominal 12-volt battery. You need 16S or a lower voltage motor. Otherwise, you screwed yourself.


What is the best way to do this?

You already listed the only two options:

More cells in series
A DC-DC converter

You say that neither one is possible. Well, then, you're doomed.
Consider instead reducing the voltage requirement of the load: buy an EV wheel that operates at a lower voltage. Also, it is quite likely that the EV wheel you have now can operate at that lower voltage, at the expense of being limited to a lower top speed and lower power.
